# Chrome can't use Shape Detection API

Tags: javascript, frontend

I want to use Shape Detection API in Chrome of the Windows 7.The Chrome version is `58.0.3029.110` . And I also turn the flag `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`.

But I run the demo,it can't work.

This is the [demo](https://codepen.io/miguelao/pen/PmJWro)

Comment: `only the Mac and Android implementations are wired so far. Win10 will be coming soon`. - [source](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=646035#c16) - no mention of win7 at all either

Comment: What could be clearer about the message *Face Detection not supported*?

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you